# Check whether either all variables are empty or none of them

Tags: bash

I have four variables in my bash script: `foo`, `bar`, `baz`, and `quax`. I have a code I want to run if either all of them or none of them are empty.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: You should include an example of something you tried and its wrong output to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I am not trying to solve a bug. I don't know what you want me to exemplify here. @tjm3772

Comment: If you aren't trying to solve a bug then the question is off-topic on SO. See: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Please edit your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: @Cyrus I simply don't know how to approach the situation. I tried chaining the test commands and all my attempts failed with syntax errors.

Comment: @tjm3772 I don't believe this question is off-topic. If you believe so, please feel free to vote for close.

Comment: `I tried chaining the test commands and all my attempts failed with syntax errors` that sounds like you have an attempted solution(s) with a bug. Why not include it in the question?

Comment: @tjm3772 Because then it becomes an XY question. My purpose was not fixing my attempts, my purpose was figuring out the best way to approach the situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for a single expression that evaluates to true when the four variables are all empty or all non-empty then you could use a [parameter expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) like `${var:++1}` inside an arithmetic expression for counting the number of variables that are not empty; then you'll just need to test the *modulo* four of that number:

```bash
if (( (0 ${foo:++1} ${bar:++1} ${baz:++1} ${quax:++1}) % 4 == 0 ))
then
    # do your stuff
fi
```

**note:** `${var:++1}` expands to `+1` when `$var` is non-empty, and to nothing otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest with `bash`:

```
if [[ "$foo$bar$baz$quax" == "" ]]; then echo "all are empty"; fi

if [[ "$foo" != "" ]] && [[ "$bar" != "" ]] &&
   [[ "$baz" != "" ]] && [[ "$quax" != "" ]]; then
   echo "none is empty";
fi
```